# Should "A Multipurpose Quine" be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopening

[A Multipurpose Quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179300/a-multipurpose-quine)

This challenge was closed for the reason that it was unclear what the challenge was asking. The main reason was that the challenge required all outputted quines to not be altercations of each other, which is impossible. The question was edited a few days ago, and clarified what makes a quine different from other quines. Due to that edit, I believe that the question now fits our standards and now can be reopened. What does the community think?

Comment: I personally agree, but since I've already opened it once before, and it got re-closed again (and only after that the Levensteihn distance formula was added), I'm unable to re-open again.

Comment: the problem is that the question is posed in a way that it's possible to get an infinite score really easy. I think that since the original poster has put a copy in the Sandbox, we can leave this one closed and let them repost it